# X-frame origins block, is there an alternative to embedding? VUE JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm building a dashboard which needs to link to our training and HR sites. I've tried using iframe, object and embed in a variety of ways but keep getting the "X-Frame-Options to 'sameorigin' error, which is understandable!

Is there an alternative that I can use so I can display the respective websites through the dashboard I'm building?

Here's what I've been trying so far.

```
<iframe id="inlineFrameExample" title="Inline Frame Example" width="100%" 
   height="1000px" 
   src="https://www.complianceserve.com/go/complianceserve/about/ReturnUrl=/">
</iframe>
```

```
<object data="https://www.complianceserve.com/go/complianceserve/about/? 
  ReturnUrl=/" width="100%" height="1000px" type="text/html">
    <embed src="https://www.complianceserve.com/go/complianceserve/about/? 
    ReturnUrl=/" width="100%" height="1000px" />
</object>
```

As a quick fix I've just added buttons and icons which open a new tab and go directly to the external sites. Unfortunately it's not exactly what the business is looking for.

Comment: If you want to embed them, then the sites have to stop forbidding you from embedding them!